# Following a html link from an iphone app

Tags: iphone, html

I have a couple of html links attached to buttons in my app.
I'm just wondering whats the best practice for following a html link in an iphone app.

I'm not sure if the app should exit and open safari or if a web container should be used etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no real best practice, it's whatever you think your users would appreciate. Some apps offer the best of both worlds, by putting a UIWebView in their app to view web content and then a button to open the same page in Safari.

Comment: thanks.
Could you point me towards the right section of the docs for launching safari with a url from iphone. I not sure what to search for

Comment: To launch safari from a URL, use: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myURL];` where `myURL` is an `NSURL` object.